# Code does not work in visual studio code but works in repl.it or any online complier. I pretty much get a runtime error on vscode and am forced to end

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, runtime-error

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// choose(n,m) returns how many ways there are to choose m items from
//   a set of n items
// requires: 0 <= m, 0 <= n
int choose(int n, int m)
{
    if (m == 0 || m == n)
    {
        return 1;
    } // base case

    // recursive step
    return (choose(n - 1, m) + choose(n - 1, m - 1)); // continues until we have exhausted the
    // number of possibilities to choose from, base case then terminates it
    // taken from the assignment sheet
}

// num_divisors_up_to_k(n,k) returns the number of positive divisors
//   of n that are less than or equal to k
// requires: 1 <= k <= n
int num_divisors_up_to_k(int n, int k)
{
    if (k == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    } // base case

    if (n % k == 0) // if divisible by k return 1 and call recursively
    {
        // call function again moving to next number
        return 1 + num_divisors_up_to_k(n, k - 1);
    }

    else // otherwise return 0 and call recursively
    {
        return 0 + num_divisors_up_to_k(n, k - 1); // next number
    }
}

// is_prime(n) returns true if n is a prime number and false otherwise
// requires: 1 <= n
bool is_prime(int n)
{

    if (n < 2) // 2 is the lowest prime number
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 2; (i * i) <= n; i++) // loop through each element
    {
        if (n % i == 0) // if divisible by i its not prime so return false
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // num is prime
}

// collatz(n) returns the number of steps it takes to reach 1 by
//   by repeatedly applying the Collatz mapping on n; prints each
//   number in the sequence starting at n
// requires: 1 <= n
int collatz(int n)
{
    if (n == 1) // base case
    {
        
        return 0;
    }
    // print n
    printf("%d ", n);
    // even
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        // adding 1 and calling collatz again with next value
        return 1 + collatz(n / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        // same thing as even just with the method for odd
        return 1 + collatz(3 * n + 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // collatz code
    int n;
    printf("enter number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (n == 1)
    {
        // cant be negative or 0
        if (n < 1)
        {
            printf("wrong input");
        }
        else
        {
            // else printing collatz sequence for input
            printf("collatz(%d): ", n);
            int steps = collatz(n);
            // print out number of steps
            printf("it took %d steps\n", steps);
        }
        // next input
        printf("enter number: \n");
    }
    // TESTS CASES

    // choose function
    assert(choose(2, 1) == 2);
    assert(choose(4, 2) == 6);
    assert(choose(10, 10) == 1);
    assert(choose(8, 2) == 28);
    assert(choose(0, 0) == 1);

    // num_divisors_up_to_k function
    assert(num_divisors_up_to_k(9, 9) == 3);
    assert(num_divisors_up_to_k(1, 1) == 1);
    assert(num_divisors_up_to_k(100, 100) == 9);
    assert(num_divisors_up_to_k(0, 0) == 0);

    // is_prime function
    assert(is_prime(10) == false);
    assert(is_prime(2) == true);
    assert(is_prime(7919) == true);
    assert(is_prime(479001599) == true);

    // collatz
    assert(collatz(5) == 5);
    assert(collatz(13) == 9);
    assert(collatz(1) == 0);

    printf("PASSED\n");
}
```

Code does not work in visual studio code but works in repl.it or any online complier. I pretty much get a runtime error on vscode and am forced to end the program myself. im not very good with the technicality of IDE's and I know this code doesn't work as intended but I can't fix it unless I can properly compile it and see the output. if anyone can help me my discord tag is ansh#1234 or you can reply here. looking forward to making this work and thank you in advance

Here is the output on VSCode:

[image: vscode]

Here is the output on **repl.it**:

[image: repl.it]

Comment: This makes no sense: `while (n == 1)    {   if (n < 1) { } else { }   }`.  Your loop will only be entered if n is 1, so testing for `n < 1` will always fail, and the else will always be executed with `n = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

There is configuration issue inyour Visual Studio Code setup. You should just run the program manually in a shell window by typing:

```sh
cd /Users/ansh/Desktop/c
gcc assignment1.c -o assignment1
./assignment1
```